# Excel userform displaying wrong information when Edit button is pressed

Tags: excel, vba, forms

[image]

Im working on a personal project for learning purposes. I cant figure out why the wrong info gets populated in my userform when i select the edit button. It forces me to re-enter the the information again to edit that line. What am i doing wrong to get the info to populate the wrong txt boxes?

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()

    If Selected_List = 0 Then
    
            MsgBox "NO row is selected.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
            
            Exit Sub
    
    End If

    'Code to update the value to respective controls
    
    Me.txtRowNumber.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 0), _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A:A"), 0)
    
    Me.txtJCN.Value = Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 1)
    
    Me.cmbLocation.Value = Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 2)

    Me.cmbStatus.Value = Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 3)
    
    Me.txttaskname.Value = Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 4)
    
    Me.txtdateopened.Value = Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 5)
    
    Me.txtproblem.Value = Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 6)
    
    Me.txtfixaction.Value = Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 8)
    
    MsgBox "Please make the required changes and clock on 'SAVE' button to update.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
    

End Sub
```

I tried re-organizing the me.txt to align in order. that didnt work. Im very enexperienced with VBA code.

Comment: I guess column is zero based, so the first column is 0 not 1

Answer (score 0):

First column is 0 i.e. `List(i,0)`

```vb
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()

    Dim rngA As Range, i As Long
    Set rngA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A:A")

    With Me.lstDatabase
        i = .ListIndex
        If i < 0 Then
            MsgBox "No row is selected.", vbExclamation, "Edit"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'Code to update the value to respective controls
        Me.txtRowNumber.Value = Application.Match(.List(i, 0), rngA, 0)
        Me.txtJCN.Value = .List(i, 0)
        Me.cmbLocation.Value = .List(i, 1)
        Me.cmbStatus.Value = .List(i, 2)
        Me.txttaskname.Value = .List(i, 3)
        Me.txtdateopened.Value = .List(i, 4)
        Me.txtproblem.Value = .List(i, 5)
        Me.txtfixaction.Value = .List(i, 7)
    End With
    '
    MsgBox "Please make the required changes and " & _
           "clock on 'SAVE' button to update.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
    
End Sub
```